# visual paradigm reverse java code, class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, visual-paradigm

Using this tool the classes corresponding to my code were created.

Each class has attributes with its getter and setter methods.
The attributes are created in the diagram but with the label << Property >> Without the corresponding methods, as you can see from the image.
[image]
Moreover, lists are not attributed to the type List , even if I change the association into aggregation.

The label << Property >> tells you precisely an attribute which correspond getter and setter?

I could not find anything about this label in the UML documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call label is a stereotype. Attributes with a `<<Property>>` stereotype are usually marked this way to tell a code generator that appropriate getter and setter methods shall be created if the target language supports (or requires) that.

Lists do not depend on the composition symbol but on the multiplicity which is barely readable, but I guess the dots near the associations are asterisks (for any multiplicity). The dots at the end of the associations are isOwned attributes (saying the the dot-marked class owns the association).

Comment: sorry, i mean that in my code "own" attribute is List<Product>, but  in diagram i have "ownList: Product" and not "own: List<Product>", why? it's the same?

Comment: That might be the way VP interprets it. Unfortunately I can't help much with this special product. You need to imagine that these products use an internal compiler to analyze sources. And there are different ways to convert between computer languages and UML. This is similar to translating between different human languages.